# How do I pass data between components in Angular 2?

Tags: typescript, angular

I have a component on Angular 2.47 alpha version, which was looking like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: `
      <div class="col-md-4" *ngFor="#data of datas">
        <OtherComponent [dataDetails]="data"></OtherComponent>
        <br />
      </div>
    </div>
  `
})
export class App {
    datas: Array<Object> = [];
}
```

The code was working properly; The `data` is been passed to `OtherComponent` as expected on a loop. But until I tried moving to angular 2 beta version, it stopped working and started to throw this error:

```
Can't bind to 'dataDetails' since it isn't a known native property ("
```

Have I made a mistake?

Comment: check your imports i.e component from angular2/core and onInit changed to ngOnInit it may produce the error.

Comment: I think OtherComponent needs an @Input decorator property

Comment: @PardeepJain: I didnt get your comment.

Comment: i mean to say check for `import {Component, View, ngOnInit} from 'angular2/core';` and because onInit now changed with ngOnInit.

Comment: You have an extra closing `</div>` tag, but that should throw a different error.

Comment: I can't help you, as I had the same error message when I was using kebab-case in my selectors and it wnet when I put in camelCase - you already seem to have camelCase

Answer (score 1):

There are three possible issues here, two of which have been mentioned:

- `OtherComponent` needs to be declared in `directives` on `App`
- `dataDetails` needs to be declared in `inputs` on `OtherComponent`

Assuming both of those are true, are you certain that `OtherComponent` is being loaded before `App`? If not, you need to use [`forwardRef`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/forwardRef-function.html):

Replace:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: `...`,
    directives: [OtherComponent]
})
```

with:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: `...`,
    directives: [forwardRef(()=>OtherComponent) OtherComponent] //untested syntax
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to inform Angular 2 that `OtherComponent` exists. Assuming the class has the same name, this is what your Component decorator should look like:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: `...`,
    directives: [OtherComponent]
})
```

Unrelated, custom tag names shouldn't be camel-case, they should be kebab-case. When they land in the DOM they become lowercase, which is inconsistent with your code. Also, custom tag names are supposed to have [at least one dash](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5968) in them.